# Do SpriteBuilder's Smart Sprite Sheet need to be loaded to memory?

Tags: graphics, cocos2d, memory

When I create an Smart Sprite Sheet Folder using SpriteBuilder and publish it, must I load that SpriteSheet into memory "FrameCache" with code or does SpriteBuilder do this automatically (so I just have to access any image inside of SpriteSheet?)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, whenever you make a sprite using any spritesheet, that spritesheet will be loaded automatically. So you don't have to load anything.

Comment: Any source / link to confirm this assumption?